# Не получается подменить результат метода. Mockito

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, junit, mockito

Есть класс SessionManagerTest. В нем я делаю мок, как положенно и пытаюсь подменить результат метода getCurrentSession.

```
private SessionManager sessionManager;
@Before
    public void init() {
        sessionManager = Mockito.mock(SessionManager.class);
        Mockito.when(sessionManager.getCurrentSession(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(new MyClassSession(1, 20171111, "cash_user"));
    }
```

сам метод, из класса SessionManager

```
public MyClassSessionI getCurrentSession(BridgeConfigI bridgeConfig, Integer sessionDay) throws MyException {
        MyClassSessionI myClassSession = getSessionFromCache(bridgeConfig.getMandatoryParam("user"), sessionDay);
        if (Optional.ofNullable(myClassSession).isPresent()) {
            sessionValidator.check(myClassSession);
            return myClassSession;
        }
        myClassSession = getSessionFromDatabase(bridgeConfig, sessionDay);
        if (Optional.ofNullable(myClassSession).isPresent()) {
            sessionValidator.check(vinnicaSession);
            addSessionToCache(myClassSession);
        }
        return myClassSession;
    }
```

Но результат не подменяеться. И выполняеться метод getCurrentSession.
Не могу понять почему именно так. 
Класс SessionManager вызываеться в классе MyClassBridge

```
  @Autowired
    @Qualifier("SessionManager")
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public CancelResponseI process(CancelRequestI cancelRequest) throws BiserException {
        fillSessionUserAndPasswordByPointType(cancelRequest.getPaymentPackInfo());
        Integer date = prepareSessionDate(cancelRequest.getFirstPayment());
        MyClassSessionI myClassSession = getSession(date);
        ControllerI controller = controllerFactory.createNewInstance(bridgeConfig);
        CancelResponse response = controller.cancel(cancelRequestBuilder.buildRequest(cancelRequest.getFirstPayment(), myClassSession));
        cancelResponseValidator.validateOuterResponse(response);
        return new CancelResponse(myClassSession.getSessionId().toString());
    }


    private MyClassSessionI getSession(Integer date) throws BiserException {
        return sessionManager.getCurrentSession(bridgeConfig, date);
    }
```

Comment: А что вы вообще запускаете? Мок ваш работает только в пределах теста SessionManagerTest. Но я нигде не вижу из вашего кода как именно вызывается ваш этот метод getCurrentSession(). Выложите такой код, чтобы можно было увидеть весь поток выполнения.

Comment: В самом конце вопроса есть метод getSession,  который вызывает getCurrentSession. Посмотрите внимательно

Comment: Вы похоже совсем запутались в том, что запускаете (иначе бы выложили правильные куски кода). То что у вас в последней строчке этот какой то код, я подозреваю из рабочего приложения. И я подозреваю менеджется он спрингом. Он вообще никакого отношеня к вашему тесту не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

похоже у вас `@Autowired` стоит над

```
private SessionManager sessionManager;
```

потому что в ином случае вываливалось бы NPE. Раз его нет, значит кто-то кладет в `sessionManager` реальный объект класса `SessionManager`

Comment: добавил еще кусок кода

Comment: @drakonchik20 стороннему человеку сложно связать ваши куски кода. Выложите класс теста и класс который тестируете. Либо только методы, но дополните информацией о полях этих объектов, как создаются и инициализируются

Comment: @drakonchik20 из того, что есть. Spring автоматом подставляет зависимость. Про объект созданные в тесте он не в курсе. Самое простое решение - перенесите инициализацию SessionManager  в конструктор и в тесте создавайте объект тестирумого класса, самостоятельно добавляя зависимый объект

Comment: А самое сложное?

Comment: Просто мне код менять нельзя

Comment: @drakonchik20 второй вариант это создание отдельного контекста под тесты и создание нужного бина там. У тестового бина уже мокнуть сервис. Третий вариант сложнее, создать бин и через рефлексию подменить сервис